# Duplicate Records on AGOL

Tags: arcgis-online, duplication

I recently uploaded to AGOL a feature service layer with a relationship table (many to many). While configuring the layer, I found out that for some reason the table counts more records than what really exists. Selection of the records does correspond to the actual number of features.

Has anybody encountered something like this?

[image]

Comment: can you do a query on the service directly and see how many results are returned or can you share the service and I can take a look?

Comment: Hi Russ. Sorry for the delayed answer. I've been trying to find solutions for the problem- unsuccessfully so far. I'm still waiting for my boss to review the problem before I do something else. I'll be in touch if necessary. Thanks